# how to php preg_match to grab date

Tags: php, preg-match

Trying to just grab the date in this url

`upload/Standard Project/test/04-12-2011/1.jpg`

the url will change names and so will the date, but it will always be in the same format.

Any idea of how would be great. I tried to date it using substr but realized that wont work because the url can change.

Comment: how much will the url change, if the date is in the same position , you can just explode on /, even if it moves explode on / and loop through the results is not a bad idea

Comment: Is that `April 12th` or `December 4th`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$str = 'upload/Standard Project/test/04-12-2011/1.jpg';
if(preg_match('@/([0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4})/@', $str, $matches))
  var_dump($matches[1]);
```